# How to store Affine Transfroms with PostGis 2.3

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

I need to store a specific 3D affine transformation for each entry of a table.
Such transformations are later used in order to provide representation of geometries in the entry local reference frame. Notice that I might have a lot of these transformations and thus I would rather avoid defining a custom SRID for each one.

I know that I can apply a transformation using the function [ST_Affine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html)
and providing all the transformation parameters.

What is the best way of storing the 6 affine parameters? I do not want to use six columns. I would rather prefer having a single column containing all the transformation parameters. Is there a default type to represent this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using PostGIS/PostgreSQL and it's always the same number of parameters for an affine transformation, you can use PostgreSQL [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) to store the affine parameters as a single field.